# How do I move the icon above the button text?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm new.
Can you tell me how to move the icon above the text?

```
<v-toolbar-items>
      <v-btn text title>
        <v-icon>mdi-magnify</v-icon>
        Test
      </v-btn>
      </v-toolbar-items>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [open feature request](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/6847), but the only way I've found to achieve this is to use a CSS override:

```
.v-btn__content {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
}

<v-btn icon>
    <v-icon>mdi-heart</v-icon>
    <div>Text</div>
</v-btn>
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/55N0Ttd1da

Comment: Yes it works, can it only be applied to some buttons?
https://photos.app.goo.gl/MFyNWpAnGophTCE7A

Comment: I succeeded, I add a class to the necessary button, class="up_icon". then I use css:
.up_icon > span {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}